# Is it possible to have ANOVA-type assesment of main efects in quantile mixed linear regression?

Tags: anova, quantile-regression, effects

As in the title. I would like to assess the main effects by applying a joint test to the quantile regression. In R it's done by lqmm(), but neither anova, Anova, emmeans, or multcomp support it. I started wondering if it's possible to speak about ANOVA here in terms of medians?

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46434/quantile-regression-which-standard-errors