# r quantreg - quantile regression with clustered standard errors

Tags: r, quantile-regression, clustered-standard-errors, sandwich

I fit a quantile regression using `quantreg:::rq` on clustered data. I use the Huber sandwich estimator to obtain cluster-corrected standard errors, which is indicated by the `se = 'nid'` argument in `summary.rq`.

But here's my confusion:

```
q_1 <- rq(y ~ y, tau = .5, data = data)
summary.rq(q_1, se = 'nid')
```

Shouldn't there be an argument to specify on which variable is my data clustered? Thanks for the help!

*Below is a similar question to mine, but it doesn't resolve my specific confusion:

[Quantile regression: Which standard errors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46434/quantile-regression-which-standard-errors)